# Как лучше всего реализовать в программе обновление адресов DNS-серверов с помощью OpenNIC

Tags: c++, c, qt, winapi, dns

Существует "сервис" [OpenNIC](https://www.opennic.org/) позволяет получить адреса DNS-серверов с помощью API, для доступа к доменным именам .lib и тому подобным:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эти адреса DNS-серверов нужно вносить в настройки адаптера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что эти адреса иногда перестают работать и поэтому их приходится обновлять.

Мы решили написать программу для автоматизации этого процесса.

Варианты которые пришли на ум:

1. Что-бы программа каждые 30 минут делала запрос к API OpenNIC получала адреса и вносила в настройки адаптера.
2. Сделать что-то подобное VPN чтобы когда пользователь нажимал подключить то "включались" эти адреса DNS-серверов и он мог заходить на .lib домены, а когда он нажимал отключиться то он уже бы не смог зайти на домены типа .lib.

**Хотелось бы узнать как лучше всего это можно сделать каким способом?** *Можно приложить какие-то куски кода или приложить ссылки на сторонние библиотеки, я хотел бы чтобы нас натолкнули на какой нибудь способ. Спасибо.*

**Хорошие ли способы которые выше? Тогда какими путями их можно реализовать? С помощью WinApi или сторонними библиотеками?** *Мне очень нравится второй способ, который я привёл выше, но я даже не знаю как сделать.*

Для первого способа я нашёл на "международном" [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955919/need-a-way-in-c-to-set-the-dns-servers-on-all-interfaces), но особо не понятно хороший ли это способ или нет. При этом ещё же нужно что-бы это сделать для всех адаптеров в Windows я думаю, что способ немного "колхозный".

Для второго способа я читал про [TAP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP), который используется в VPN, но толком не разобрался можно ли с помощью него что-то сделать.

Как я понял VPN устанавливает драйвер который "создаёт" виртуальный сетевой интерфейс и с помощью этого клиент VPN творит волшебство:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я еще пробовал искать по GitHub подобные проекты, но нашёл какие-то [скрипты](https://github.com/kewlfft/opennic-up) для Linux, но нужно для Windows.

А вот если внести адреса в настройки этого виртуального адаптера, то ничего не работает.

*Саму программу мы начали делать в Qt C++, но можно дать примеры и на других языках.*